# React not rendering on rails static page view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-dom

So in View, Rails static_pages root.html.erb is showing on http://localhost:3000/

> app/view/static_pages/root.html.erb

```
<main id="root"></main>
<h1> from root.html.erb file </h1>
```

> app/frontend/waitlist.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const root = document.getElementById('root');

  ReactDOM.render(<h1>react render</h1>, root);
});
```

> webpack.config.js

```
    var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: "./frontend/waitlist.jsx",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app', 'assets', 'javascripts'),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: [/\.jsx?$/, /\.js?$/],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['env', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", "*"]
  }
};
```

Not sure why waitlist.jsx part is not working, no errors show. Just ran rails server and only seeing rails view with no reactDOM.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your erb file is missing a reference to the bundle.js file.

Add:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "bundle" %>
```

to the bottom of your erb file.

Comment: I tried including it at the bottom of root.html.erb, but it still does not show.

GET http://localhost:3000/javascripts/bundle.js 404 (Not Found) this shows on chrome console

Comment: Have you checked to see if webpack has actually built bundle.js?

Comment: Okay, I just found out there is no bundle.js on my output directory. Not sure why though. I ran my server with 'rails s' on my console with that webpack.config.js up there.

Comment: resolved, it was problem with bundle.js after fixing up package.json and webpack.config.js it created bundle.js

Comment: @hd30622 glad you got it working. I take it you also needed the inclusion of the javascript_include_tag?

Comment: Nope I didn't need the javascript_include_tag I had that on application.html.erb